# 2 xamarin apps with partly shared UI?

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible to structure a xamarin solution to share parts of views in the app between two different apps, e.g. login view and logic is shared between two apps but the main functionality is implemented per app?

**Note, I'm not talking about sharing between ios and droid!**

I have an app (on ios and droid). I now want to create a similar app with a slightly different target operation, but reuse a lot of functionality that is common e.g. login, change password, etc etc. If possible I'd like to reuse them almost totally as is, e.g. both logic and UI (layout, resources etc). Today I have a structure like:

- MyApp.Droid
- MyApp.Ios
- MyApp.Common (shared business logic)

I'd like to have it:

- MyApp1.Droid   (Specific app functionality)
- MyApp2.Droid   (Specific app functionality)
- MyApp.DroidCommon  (Common views like login, change password etc.)

  ---
- MyApp1.Ios
- MyApp2.Ios
- MyApp.IosCommon

  ---
- MyApp.Common (shared business logic between ios and droid)

...our something similar/other that lets me share parts of an app in multiple apps. Is this possible and how would I go about implementing application, resources etc?

Comment: Ok so you want that structure. But where is the problem? Your post odes not contain a question? What would you like us to help you with?

Comment: Yeah i would like to know the same thing as Patrick said what do you want us to help you with?

Comment: "Is it possible...?"  Yes, of course it is.

Comment: Ok, sorry If I'm not clear. I know how to separate business logic but how do I do when I want to split the eg android project into one part with shared ui, like login etc, and one with the actual app features such as input form and reports? Both projects (app1 and common) would contain layout and resources. Are they shared between the projects or needs to be duplicated, e.g background, buttons etc? Only one of them projects should have the application.cs implementation, right?  If both objects needs access to it how should i do?

Comment: One option would perhaps to just share the relevant files in the different projects, e.g. loginactivity.cs would be added to both MyApp1.droid and MyApp2.droid instead of having a MyApp.DroidCommon project!? Just seems a bit "hacky"?

Comment: If you just want to share UI in two app, i advice hybird app to achieve it, you could wirte HTML pages ,then used webview to load the HTML page in these apps

Comment: Thanks @LeonLu-MSFT but my app is already in production so to rewrite it is not an option. After some trial and error it looks like it will work as I described above. I'm still not sure about the best way to structure the app projects when it comes to resources etc but at least it now runs.

Comment: Ok,Thanks for your sharing.